# AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'

Tags: ansible, templating, ansible-template

An error occurs when preparing the template. Who can tell you how to fix it?

Variables, if necessary, can also be edited.

```
  vars:
    AllСountry:
         - "name1"
         - "name2"
    name1:
         - "region1a"  
         - "region1b"   
    name2:
         - "region2a"
         - "region2b"
```

Code

```
{% for country in AllСountry %}   
{name: "{{ country }}",{% for count in {{ country }} %}My country = {{ count }}
{% endfor %}{% endfor %}
```

the result is an error
AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'

Yes in the end I expect to get the output of the entire list from

```
name: "name1  My country = "region1a" My country = "region1b"   
name: "name2: My country = "region2a" My country = "region2b"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens because you are nesting a expression delimiter `{{` in a statement delimiter `{%` in Jinja here:

```
{% for count in {{ country }} %}
{#              ^--- right there #}
```

In order to achieve what you are looking to do, you can use the [`vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/lookup/vars.html) lookup.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: >
          {% for country in AllCountry %}   
          {name: "{{ country }}",{% for count in lookup('vars', country) %}My country = {{ count }}
          {% endfor %}{% endfor %}
      vars:
        AllCountry:
          - name1
          - name2
        name1:
          - region1a
          - region1b 
        name2:
          - region2a
          - region2b
```

This yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "    {name: \"name1\",My country = region1a My country = region1b     {name: \"name2\",My country = region2a My country = region2b \n"
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```